# Find the matching word C#

Tags: c#, string-matching

I have 3 strings, i would like find matches

http://www.vkeong.com/2011/food-drink/heng-bak-kut-teh-delights-taman-kepong/#comments
http://www.vkeong.com/2009/food-drink/sen-kee-duck-satay-taman-desa-jaya-kepong/
http://www.vkeong.com/2008/food-drink/nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru/

```
for each link above=="nasi-lemak"
{
  found!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to see if a longer string contains a specific shorter string, use `String.Contains`.

For your example:

```
string[] urlStrings = new string[] 
{
    @"http://www.vkeong.com/2011/food-drink/heng-bak-kut-teh-delights-taman-kepong/#comments"
    @"http://www.vkeong.com/2009/food-drink/sen-kee-duck-satay-taman-desa-jaya-kepong"
    @"http://www.vkeong.com/2008/food-drink/nasi-lemak-wai-sik-kai-kepong-baru/"
}

foreach(String url in urlStrings)
{
    if(url.Contains("nasi-lemak"))
    {
        //Your code to handle a match here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [String.IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof) method.

```
foreach(string url in url_list)
{
    if(url.IndexOf("nasi-lemak") != -1)
    {
        // Found!
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to ask: why is this preferable to .Contains?

Comment: @AllenG - maybe for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/net-is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof

Comment: Well, yes, it stands to reason that just finding the index is faster than finding the index and then verifying that the result isn't -1, but since that's exactly what this solution is doing anyway, I'm not seeing a difference.  Not saying it's a bad solution, just looking for a reason that I'd do this instead of the native .Contains to see if a String contained a certain substring.

Comment: It's just one possible solution. Readability-wise, yeah I'd probably go with `.Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

Surely we also need a LINQ answer :)

```
var matches = urlStrings.Where(s => s.Contains("nasi-lemak"));

// or if you prefer query form. This is really the same as above
var matches2 = from url in urlStrings
               where url.Contains("nasi-lemak")
               select url;

// Now you can use matches or matches2 in a foreach loop
foreach (var matchingUrl in matches)
     DoStuff(matchingUrl);
```

Comment: My preference is the first in this example