# Reading the userAgent with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which reads the userAgent and does some logic based on the values matched using indexOf:

```
String userAgent;
userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
// If it's not IE
if (userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE") < 0)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Dashboard" });
}
// If it's IE BUT ChromeFrame
else if(userAgent.IndexOf("ChromeFrame") > -1)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Dashboard" });
}
// It's just IE
else
{
    return View("ChromeFrame");
}
```

If it's IE then it should return the view or if its IE but contains ChromeFrame then it should redirect and it's another browser then it should redirect as well.

I think the problem is with the `> 0` part of the code. What is the correct way of comparing info? Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't change the code in a way that the answers you already got don't apply anymore...

Answer (score 8):

Just use the  [contains method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/net-is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof), which will make your code less cryptic and less error-prone.

```
if (userAgent.Contains("MSIE"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Dashboard" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `> -1` as otherwise it will not work if the substring is at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOf` returns -1 if the string is not found... see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) for reference.