# How to search for a specific string of character in another string

Tags: java, android

i have the following in my code.

```
String viit = "android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM";
```

and

```
String biit = "READ";
```

How do i search if viit contains biit?

Please note that viit is not a sentence but more like a word.

Comment: if viit **contains** biit - yeah that will do it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: I think you could put into the question more details if you want

Comment: viit.contains(biit)

Comment: @vica you can use java string contains() method searches the sequence of characters in this string. It returns true if sequence of char values are found in this string otherwise false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search the whole string for a specific word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740493/how-to-search-the-whole-string-for-a-specific-word)

Comment: `System.out.println(viit.contains(biit));`

Answer (score 4):

Simple: you use one of the many methods on String, such as [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
if (viit.contains(biit)) {
```

which will give true for an "exact" match. If you need something "more fuzzy", you would be turning to [matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) fore example which takes a **regular expression**. Those allow for a great deal of "fine tuned" [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to be used.

Comment: Then you want to rework your question and put up a [mcve]. Because then you are doing something wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.

```
String viit = "android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM"; 
String biit = "READ";
if(viit.contains(biit)) {
   //int index = viit.indexOf(biit);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the java String.indexOf() method.

In your example, this would be something like that:

```
boolean hit = viit.indexOf(biit) == -1 ? true : false;
```

You can omit the boolean if you don't need it, if indexOf has no hit it will return -1.

Or use the String.contains() method which gives a boolean straight away.

Comment: Be careful about using :: like this. In 2017 :: looks like a method refernce; which is probably not want you mean here.

Comment: It's meant to be referring to a method, sorry. I've been working with PHP a little bit and they document all their methods this way. Is there a standard pseudo-code or otherwise widely-used way to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I edited my answer, that was a stupid comment on my side

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the string like below

```
if( string.indexOf("READ") >= 0 ) { 
   Log.i("available", "true");
}else {
   Log.i("not available", "false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use String indexOf method. the contains method uses indexof underneath.

regards