# Checking the first char in string

Tags: c#, performance

I know 2 ways to check if the first char in string are some char.

```
var str = "/checking";
if (str.StartsWith("/"))
    return;
```

and the over way:

```
var str = "/checking";
if (str[0] == '/')
    return;
```

In this case (where I need to check the char, not the substring) whinh way would be faster? And is there any difference?

Comment: `StartsWith` is more readable and it’s not slow, so you would generally pick it. (And it works when `str == ""`.) If you need the *fastest* one for your case, benchmark them.

Comment: Probably the second way, but it's not going to be measurable. In any case, if you care that much, you could always test it.

Comment: You might find value in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof

Comment: Also: please read: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: The second is certainly faster, no function call overhead, etc. However, you don't have an is empty check. Validation always complicates 'fast' things.

Comment: Which one is faster: [Measure It](https://github.com/idvorkin/measureitdotnet)

Comment: `if(str.Contains("/"))` you can use that too this is more of an opinionated question by the way.. test all suggested approaches and see which one performs best under your usecase

Comment: It depends, check it yourself, results can be little weird for you :D : http://rextester.com/QWXP17187
To sum it up:  StartsWith is optimized, but have same overhead, so for lower tours will be slower.

Comment: @sTrenat bigger difference than I expected. You can use StringComparison.Ordinal to close the gap a bit.

Comment: Ok, so, thanks everyone for the replies! @MethodMan, I can't use contains - I need to know what is the first char, and contains can return true if the string would be something like "asdasd/gsadfsdf", and that would be false result for me.

Comment: @sTrenat, very interesting. But according to your results - the direct method is a way faster. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way will be much faster.
The first way is designed to handle a string thus its code needs to be compatible with different comparisons as well.
The second way will work only for this condition => will take less time

Source Code: [StartsWith](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2514)

Comment: Do you have any links substantiating you statements?

Comment: @zx485 You don't need one, only logic:
The first one will try to run on a string (multiple chars) and will contain more conditions and more fail-safes, when the other one will only try to access and won't even try to block the 'crash' in case of no char in index

Comment: @Administrator, just as I thought. Anyway - thanks.
I just didn't know that there is a such big difference, as sTrenat mention in the comments -  rextester.com/QWXP17187

Comment: @Vlad-00003 no problem, but just mark the answer as valid if it helped you :)