# How to check if list contains all string of another list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a object list. That object contains a string List. Like that:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    ...
    IList<string> StringList;
}
```

And I have a list of words to search on StringList. I need to search on a ObjectA list, and find all ObjectA that have all words (parts of all words).

So I did that:

```
 List<ObjectA> myObjectList;
 List<string> wordsToFind;  

 var result = myObjectList.Where(objectA => wordsToFind.All(objectA.StringList.Contains));
```

The problem is my result is getting only whole words (equals). I would like to get results that contains parts of my wordsToFind.

**Example**

```
wordsToFind = {"tes","don"};
StringListElement = {"test", "done"}
```

Should return on my select.

How can I do that?

Comment: list a contain all word in list b? how about order? is it 100% match or?

Comment: Order is irrelevant

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to provide sample inputs **and expected results based on those sample inputs**.

Comment: Do you want ordinal comparison? https://stackoverflow.com/a/498722/34092

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) is probably where you want to be, or one of its overloads

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified
>   Unicode character or string within this instance. The method returns
>   -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

```
List<ObjectA> myObjectList;
List<string> wordsToFind;  

var result = myObjectList.Where(x => x.StringList.All(y => wordsToFind.Any(z => y.IndexOf(z) >= 0)));
```

Also note the time complexity of this is atrocious

---

**Update**

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLxO0P)

Also note, if you want case insensitivity use

```
y.IndexOf(z, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

or one of the following

- `CurrentCulture` Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules and the current culture.
- `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the current culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.
- `InvariantCulture`Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules and the invariant culture.
- `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the invariant culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.
- `Ordinal` Compare strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules.
- `OrdinalIgnoreCase` Compare strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.

Comment: Thanks, Perfomance will not be a problem I guess, the lists are small. I liked your suggestion, but it is always returning empty result, idk why

Comment: @Paul added online demo

Comment: Thanks for details... I explained my needs wrong I think. All words from my search must be in my list, but I can have words on my StringList that are not on my search. I modified your sample, that should return both objects: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QqshRh

Comment: I modified your code and its working fine now! https://dotnetfiddle.net/z7Q3eW

Thanks

Comment: @Paul thanks I was asleep heh, I'll fix the answer for future readers

Answer (score 1):

The ways to do this is by using a combination of `Any` and `All`.

You need to check if **all** the elements of `wordsToFind` are substring of **any** elements in `StringList`

```
bool result = wordsToFind.All(word => currentObject.StringList.Any(str => str.Contains(word));
```

This is for one object out of the list of Objects. You can again apply `All` to that list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you

```
var wordsToFind = new List<string>{ "tes","don"};
var data= new List<ObjectA>()
{
    new ObjectA()
    {
        StringList = new List<string>{"test", "done", "blah"}
    },
    new ObjectA()
    {
        StringList = new List<string>{"test2", "done2", "blah2"}
    }
};

var result = (from item in data.Select(x => x.StringList)
              from bar in item
              from word in wordsToFind
              where bar.Contains(word)
              select bar)
              .ToList();
```

The *result* should give you

```
"test", "done","test2", "done2"
```