# How to make a TextBox when I type `@` the cursor automatically go to the begin of the textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have textBox and I want when I type `@` the cursor automatically go to the begin of the textbox (like you pressed the Home Button on the keyboard) I tried this code

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

but it's not working as I want ( like when you press the home button on keyboard )
this is the all of the code

```
private void RichTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
            checkLog = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question actually requires a Javascript solution. It's therefore not a C# or ASP.NET question.

Comment: Are you sure you execute the code when you add the @ sign. Could you provide more code please?

Comment: @John you saying there is no way to solve this ?

Comment: How exactly does it not work the way you want it to? What are you seeing, and what did you hope so see? Where have you placed this `Select()` call? Please [edit] into your question more code and more details.

Comment: No, I said your question is about Javascript as that's what is required for real-time interactive changes to your page. Web applications aren't like traditional desktop applications, so things like keypresses aren't streamed to the server.

Comment: So how does or doesn't this work? Have you placed a breakpoint and checked whether your code ends up in this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextChanged` event and `String.IndexOf` will get the job done, `String.Contains` is another option for readability and it calls `IndexOf` internally [Is String.Contains() faster than String.IndexOf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof)

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("@") > -1)
    {
        richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the work:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(richTextBox1.Text.Contains('@'))
    {
        richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
}
```

KeyPress event actually happens before the character get added to the textbox so with KeyPress it actually goes to the beginning of the textbox and then adds the '@' there.